# how to execute a PHP code periodically using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to know how to execute a PHP code periodically (for example every 5 seconds) using AJAX. This is the PHP code that I want to execute periodically:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "a new event was added";
}
?>
```

In fact, I am started in AJAX so is there anyone who can provide me a simple example about how to do that?

Comment: use `setTimeout()` javascript function to call your AJAx at specific time interval.

Comment: You just make a request to the php script via http in ajax, scheduled by a timeout callback. There are _millions_ of examples for this out on the internet. Just ask google!

Comment: @arkascha: believe me I have searched on internet about how to do that but unfortunately I haven't found any simple example with a clear explanation, as I said I am a started so what I need is a clear simple example no more. By the way, I don't know why whenever I ask a question on this web site I get -4 or -2 or something like that because some people indicate my question as not useful or not clear!!...Despite that before I ask a question I make sure that it wasn't asked before!!!...Do you know??...I have another account on this web site but on that account I am forbidden to ask questions!!

Comment: I did not downvote myself, but usually that is the result when people reading your question have the impression that you did not really invest enough into finding the answer yourself or if the way the question is asked is of low quality making answering more complex than it has to be. In this case the problem probably is that a simple ajax call to a php script is found _millions_ of times in examples, also the documentation of typical js libraries carry really easy to understand examples. What is complex about that one for example? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: @arkascha well that tutorial is pretty simple but to be honest the answer of mister Ivo Pereira (just have a look at the answer at the bottom) seems to be clearer and more useful :). By the way, I have been banned on this account to ask questions too :(, well I think I will create another account. I wonder what shall I do to to increase my reputation on this web site!!...my dream really is to have attain 10 reputations, I have worked hard and I have done my best but unfortunately in vain. Well, thanks a lot mister arkascha for your help, and I wish one day that I have reputation like you have.

Comment: You certainly will build up your knowledge, absolutely. Try answering a few questions yourself to earn some points. But take care only to answer if you are certain about your answer, good quality of postings is much much more important than just posting "anything"! That will keep your account usable. Starting new accounts is not really considered a fair use of this place, sorry to say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what exactly is AJAX?

It looks like you will be using a library for this, so take a read here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you are not planning to use jQuery, you could check this XMLHttpRequest project that is cross-browser: https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest

Make use of AJAX periodically using a setInterval of 5 seconds where you would make a call to a PHP file you have in your server that would run the code you specified.

Take the following example:

**index.html**

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("file.php", function (data) {
       console.log('Good to go, data was loaded');
       console.log(data);
    });      
}, 5000);
```

**file.php**

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "a new event was added";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...By the way, can you explain me:
1. what does the the instruction console.log() do exactly??
2. why do we use the parameter "data" here??
Thanks a lot again for your help.

Comment: console.log() do print output to your Firebug console (I hope you are using it... http://getfirebug.com). We use parameter data there be able to use the data that is sent in output from PHP in JavaScript. If the answer solve your question, mark it as correct :)

Comment: well, we suppose that the code of the file file.php is: <?php $chaine = "hello" ?> ... how can I get the value of the variable $chaine using AJAX???

Comment: You just echo the value in PHP using <?php echo 'something'; ?>. Using console.log(), alert(), or any other possible output from JavaScript you can get your data. You just need to pass in the $.get callback (that's why the data field is there, to get back to you the values that come from PHP).

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an interval and jQuery get() function:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
   $.get( "(YOUR URL)", function( data ) {
      alert( "Load was performed." );
   });      
}, 5000);
```

Comment: well, why do we use the parameter data here??